# How to host Laravel application in a sufolder along with normal php application?

Tags: php, laravel, apache, nginx, web-hosting

I have a laravel application and a normal application. I want the normal application to run when user opens `example.com/` but when the user opens `example.com/laravel_application/` I want the laravel application to run. How can I achieve this. I tried various methods like creating symlinks but I seem to be always redirected to root directory (`example.com/`) e.g. when I open `example.com/laravel_application/login`
I am open to using apache or nginx.

Answer (score 0):

- you can add whole code in common laravel project and define different routes for
  both normal and laravel for ex. when you call example.com/ define this route and 
  call it from controller. May be this will help.

Answer (score 0):

It's easier to add a subdomain for Laravel app. Otherwise, you will have to create Laravel routes based on the example.com/laravel_app path.

Answer (score 0):

**There are two solutions:**

1. Using .htaccess with mod_rewrite

Create .htaccess file on sub-folder where you put your laravel application.

and add the code in .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^public
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
```

2. You can add a index.php file containing the following code and put it under your root Laravel folder.

   `<?php`
   `header('Location: public/');`

   `?>`

Comment: Thank you for response! But I do not want 'public' written in the URL. Also, momentarily I am redirected to login page and soon redirected to root directory.